# Getting int values from SQLite

Tags: c++, c, sqlite, int

I heard of using `sqlite3_prepare_v2` instead of `sqlite_exec` to get integers from database, but I failed to find any examples. [This](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) page wasn't helpful also. Now I am getting strings from database, so I need to parse them with `atoi` and this seems to be slow and ineffective. 
There a lot of similar questions on SO, but they are about obj-c and iOS SDK. I need C/C++ hint or example.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `sqlite3_prepare` has succeeded, you must not forget to clean up the statement with `sqlite3_finalize`.
To get the result records, call `sqlite3_step` until it does not return `SQLITE_ROW`.
To get the values of the current result record, call the [sqlite3_column_* functions](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html):

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT 42", -1, &stmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    ...error...
else {
    for (;;) {
        int rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
        if (rc == SQLITE_DONE)
            break;
        if (rc != SQLITE_ROW) {
            ...error...
            break;
        }
        printf("value: %d\n", sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0));
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`sqlite3_column_int(result, columnNum);` will return one column from the current row of your result as an int.

Your prepare function is to prepare your query, it has nothing to do with how the results are interpreted. All data in sqlite3 is stored textually, you use the appropriate function to retrieve a value in the type you believe it should be.

Comment: Data [is *not* always stored as text](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format).

Comment: @CL the link you provide appears to be talking about internal record formatting, not the data as viewed by the user. http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html suggests that everything is typeless with one exception, INTEGER PRIMARY KEY columns.

Comment: The data as viewed by the user still has a type; this is what [sqlite3_column_type()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html) is for.